# Loading a javascript element via AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jwplayer

I am having a small problem and even after one hour of trying I can't solve it. I am using JW Player to play a song and it works all right. Below the player is the list of songs , once a song in the list is clicked I reload the div containing the player with AJAX and change the javascript below that div to play new song. The div loads properly but the player doesn't load at all after AJAX Call. There are no errors just the player can't instantiate the second time.

Here is the code which displays the player:

```
<div id="myDiv"><div id="myElement2">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement2").setup({
    file: "uploads/maid.mp3",
        title: "Sintel Movie Trailer",

      width: '100%',
      skin: "six/six3.xml",
      height:30

    });
</script></div>
```

Here is what happens when the new song is loaded:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML='';
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

And here is the response text from separate php File:

```
<div id="myElement2">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement2").setup({
    file: "newfilename.mp3",
        title: "file name",

      width: '100%',
      skin: "six/six3.xml",
      height:30

    });
</script>
```

But after the AJAX Call player disappears and only the text loading the player... appears. Here is the url where the player is located:
[contestlancer.com/davidicus](http://contestlancer.com/davidicus)

Answer (score 1):

InnerHTML doesn't excuse the script. Your php should respond just a path to music or video file, and then re-setup for jwplayer.

Sorry but I was out to have dinner ;-)

I think your page doesn't need ajax to get html sourp from your php, because your page already knows which music file to be played.

I don't know exactly about jwplayer, but try this code instead your original `loadXMLDoc()`.

```
function loadXMLDoc(str) {
    jwplayer("myElement2").setup({
        file: str,
        title: str,
        width: '100%',
        skin: "six/six3.xml",
        height: 30
    });
}
```

The `title` will be set as file name, but your page may be ok.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering so what should I do? Because via AJAX I won't be able to put innerHTML in script.

Answer (score 1):

My bad after some research I found out that even though the script is appended via JS call it is not executed so you must execute it . So anyone having the same problem please note that the script loaded via AJAX must be executed via eval function in javascript.

So in my content AJAX file I gave the id testing to the script that is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="testing">
```

And then in JS function I did this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML='';
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    eval(document.getElementById('testing').innerHTML);
    }
  }
```

Hope it saves someone else' time.
Regards
Ahmar